# Translate Drupal

Tags: 7

I got a question about how to translate drupal to another language so everything on the navbar dashboard etc changes to a specify language that I choice Drupal to have. I dont want the content like articles and stuff to be translated ofcourse but the rest of all the built-in drupal modueles and stuff switches to another language set. I guess there is some moduele that can do this for me?

How do I make this possible?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to *Astha Chauhan* answer,  *internationalization* module only provide functionality to translate front end content of the Drupal.

If you want to translate admin section of the Drupal, then you need to install Drupal in specific language.

Kindly find [this](https://drupal.org/documentation/install/language) link for more information.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 2):

Drupal provides a core module called translate that allows content to be translated into different languages.
There is another module called **internationalization**. 
**internationalization** : This is a collection of modules to extend Drupal core multilingual capabilities and be able to build real life multilingual sites. 
Following is the link : https://drupal.org/project/i18n

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 7 Core incorporated a series of modules designed to support multilingual websites but if you really want to build a Drupal 7 with multiple languages ​​and open our website to the world then we need to add some contributed modules and configure correctly.
I just published a very interesting post with my experience in the translation of Drupal 7: [How to build your Drupal 7 multilingual website](http://drupaltokens.com/blog/how-build-your-drupal-7-multilingual-website-truly-seo-friendly)

Good luck!

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.